# alasql doesn't write all table values to excel file using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, alasql, js-xlsx

I am able to write the table values to excel file from here (https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/How-to-export-HTML-table-to-Excel)

But when i add bottom header it doesn't import. Please find the updated example here from github link and added bottom header.

```
<table id="MyInquires">
 <thead><tr><th>#<th>Inquiry<th>Topic</thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>1
    <td>WinPhone<td>Screen
   <tr><td>2<td>iPhone<td>Keyboard
   <tr><td>3<td>Android<td>Memory
   </tbody>
  <thead><tr><th>#<th>Inquiry<th>Topic</thead>
 </table>
```

Full updated code is here (http://jsfiddle.net/arkf83b9/164/)

Could please help me, how to get bottom header as well into excel file, thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't use thead tag at bottom. use tfoot tag and try again.